# GROUP_CONCAT comma separator - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat, separator

I have a query where I am using `GROUP_CONCAT` and a custom separator as my results may contain commas: '----'

This all works well, however it is still comma separated, so my output is:

```
Result A----,Result B----,Result C----
```

How can I make it so the output is:

```
Result A----Result B----Result C----
```

I thought this was the idea of a custom separator!

Failing that, can you escape commas in your results, so I can explode in PHP by the `GROUP_CONCAT` commas?

Comment: Where are the commas coming from?  Are they the separators, or part of the results?  That part of the question isn't clear to me.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(artists.artistname, '----') is my group concat line - as you can see, I have not put comma as the separator - they are not in the results but show in the output

Answer (score 447):

Looks like you're missing the SEPARATOR keyword in the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(artists.artistname SEPARATOR '----')
```

The way you've written it, you're concatenating `artists.artistname` with the `'----'` string using the default comma separator.

Answer (score 44):

Query to achieve your requirment

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ' ') AS text FROM table_name group by id;
```

Comment: The requirement was to use `----` as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you are doing a split - join:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(split(thing, " "), '----') AS thing_name,
```

You may want to inclue `WITHIN RECORD`, like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(split(thing, " "), '----') WITHIN RECORD AS thing_name,
```

from [BigQuery API page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#aggfunctions)