# Group activity items

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following table structure for storing activity items

```
id, trackable_id, trackable_type, owner_id, owner_type
```

where trackable_id and trackable_type tells me on what object(entity) the action is performed on. For example if a User with id=1 likes a Picture with id=1

```
id, trackable_id, trackable_type, owner_id, owner_type

1,       1,            Picture,      1,        User
```

Similarly another user can like the same picture. In my news feed, I can easily display the activities performed by the users, however I would like to achieve something like this:

```
John and katy likes Picture.
```

instead of

```
John likes Picture
Kay  likes Picture.
```

I guess the way to go is to do a group by based on trackable_id and trackable_type but it returns me one row(expected result of group by). I have not used group_concat before, does it help in this kind of situation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use Like this

```
CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT( user_name SEPARATOR 'AND' ),' LIKES PICTURES')
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e07f1/4)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it helps.

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691816/group-concat-comma-separator-mysql)

`GROUP_CONCAT(columnName SEPARATOR ' AND ')`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [polymorfic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) (if no - then you should be using it).
Your method will look like the following:

```
def liked_by_string
  user_names = users.collect(&:name).to_sentence # => "John, Katty, Mark and Pete"

  "#{user_names} like the Picture"      
end
```